# ¿Cómo hacer un banner con texto y botón solo usando html?

Tags: html, botón

necesito generar este banner principal, que imagen y texto estén separados para poder trabajarlo en SEO. Cómo lo puede hacer solo usando html, qué me recomiendan? [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<a target="_blank" href=""><img data-image="oa4mwmwbrw1w" style="max-width: 100%;"
     src=""></a>
```

Comment: Es necesario HTML y CSS juntos, pero una hoja de estilos; no estilos en el HTML. Esto es recomendable. Al menos que no tengas Acceso al CSS

Comment: Sí claro, pero tengo que hacerlo obligatoriamente en HTML, no tengo acceso al CSS.

Comment: Y de dónde sacaste esa foto? Si es de un sitio web, es fácil obtener su estructura de HTML, viendo su HTML mediante click derecho y ver código fuente (si tienes suerte). Luego copia y edita a tu gusto. Que problema hay en realidad?

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz No es de un sitio de de una aplicación de edición. La idea es lograr lo mismo con HTML. Gracias.

Comment: Voy a ver si recreo uno similar

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pude recrear uno similar, usando dos div y un enlace para el botón. El div padre tiene una imágen de fondo, y un div hijo para acomodar el título, el texto y el botón que es la etiqueta `a`.

La estructura básica queda así:

```
<div>

  <div>
    <h1>Título</h1>
    <p>Texto</p>
    <a href="#">Botón</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

A cada div y etiqueta le agregué su propio estilo. Al primer div, que es el padre, le puse una imágen de fondo, lo cual es mejor que poner una etiqueta `img` (pero esto se puede modificar).

De la etiqueta `a` creé un botón, para no encerrar un botón normal en una `a`.

El snippet para el demo es el siguiente.

```html
<!-- esto es para el demo, y va en head -->
<style>
    *{box-sizing: border-box;}body{margin:0;padding:0;min-height:100vh}
</style>

<div style="
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background: #000 url(http://placeimg.com/1000/480/any);
    background-position: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover">
    
    <div style="
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 50%;
    max-width: 50%" >

        <h1 style="margin-bottom: 10px; color: #fff">¿Cómo me preparo?</h1>

        <p style="
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0; 
        color: #fff">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quia, labore?</p>

        <a href="#no" target="_blank" style="
            display: inline-block;
            text-decoration: none;
            border: 0;
            border-radius: 5px;
            margin: 10px 0;
            padding: 10px 10px;
            color: #fff;
            background-color: grey;
        ">Regístrate o ingresa</a>

    </div>

</div>
```

La imágen aleatorio del demo es de [placeimg.com](http://placeimg.com/1000/480/any).

Ésta forma de crear todo en el HTML es lo mas fácil que pude. Ya puedes formatear el código a tu gusto.

Comment: No olvides marcar ésta respuesta como aceptada, con el  **✓**, si te fue de ayuda. Servirá para otros que quieran lo mismo.